# Opening a textFile with the AssetManager and assigning it to a InputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream, android-assetmanager

Basically I think it could be a project structure issue as I'm unsure of where to put the textfile, I've made a directory assets and placed a folder called texts in that and in that have placed the myawesometext.txt.

The error I get is the exception being called that it could not find file.

I thought it could be to do with permissions but couldnt find a permissions related to it as its not external storage.

My question is if I have the file and im running the app where should I make an assets folder in the structure to be read I've double checked the spelling (no typos) it just catches my exception.

class:

```
public class AssetsTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(textView);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open("texts/myawesometext");
        String text = loadTextFile(inputStream);
        textView.setText(text);
    } catch (IOException e) { textView.setText("Couldn't load file");
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null)
            try { inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { textView.setText("Couldn't close file");
            } }
}
    public String loadTextFile(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException { ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0) byteStream.write(bytes, 0, len);
        return new String(byteStream.toByteArray(), "UTF8"); }
}
```

[image: location of file]

Thanks in Advance...
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assets folder location is not correct and your code is not correct as well. Please follow the following steps.

First, move the current `assets` folder to `src/main`.

[image: screenshot]

Second, change this line in your code from

```
inputStream = assetManager.open("texts/myawesometext");
```

to

```
inputStream = assetManager.open("texts/myawesometext.txt");
```

Comment: Genius thanks so much Tommy You're the best!! simple error looking back just couldn't see it .I was trying various different file directory names but the issue was it wasn't in src main.Thanks again

Comment: @beni Glad to hear that. Happy coding :)